# How to prove that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\ln k - \frac{1}{2}H(k)$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

It is known that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\ln k - H(k)=\gamma$$(Where $H(k)$ is the $k$th harmonic number and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant). I decided to put a random $\frac{1}{2}$ in the front of $H(k)$ and I got some limit that seems to diverge when graphed. So how do I prove that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\ln k - \frac{1}{2}H(k)$$ diverges? I was able to show that it is greater than $-\gamma$ which is a bit obvious, but that's it.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\ln k - H(k)=-\gamma$. That does not affect the convergence, though.

Comment: In terms of asymptotics
$$\log(k)-a\,H_k=-a\gamma+(1-a)\log(k)-\frac {a}{2k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\ln k - \frac{1}{2}H(k) = (\ln k - H(k)) + \frac{1}{2}H(k)
$$
is divergent as the sum of a converging and a diverging sequence.

Comment: You made it seem so easy. $+1$ for the great answer.